# Understanding Packrat Parsers in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing

[DSLs in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/) demonstrates a potential problem - **slowness** - when using `alternation` with a predictive parser:

```
Predictive parsers are fast and use linear time parsing, but a naïve implementation
of backtracking parsers can quickly degenerate to exponential time parsing. 

lazy val exp = exp ~ ("+" ~> term) |
               exp ~ ("-" ~> term) |
               term

Packrat parsers can help solve this problem of redoing the
same computation using the technique of memoization.
```

If, in the above example, my `exp` and `term` Parser's are lazily evaluated, i.e. `lazy val ...`, then does that mean that my parser is a packrat parser?

Comment: The Scaladoc for [PackratParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/scala/util/parsing/combinator/PackratParsers.html) explains what you need to do to make your parser a packrat parser. It's not just making it a `lazy val`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, marking them `lazy val` does not make them packrat parsers. What makes them packrat parsers is the underlying implementation. If you have mixed `PackratParsers` into your `Parser` then you are using packrat parsers. The fundamental difference is that the packrat parser caches already computed values (memoization) in order to prevent effort from being duplicated. Take a look at the code in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/PackratParsers.scala.